# General question about requesting to a Server

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

I know that this question maybe is silly but I would like to know.

Suppose this situation:
If I make "F5" two times in a second in order to refresh a page, is it the same that make a requests.get() petition with the same rate of time?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry your question is not completely clear. What do you mean by the last part `is it the same that make a requests.get() petition with the same rate of time?`.

Comment: I mean, suppose I make a for loop with range(0,15) requests.get(url). This will be the same that if I press f5 in the site multiple times? @PaulRooney

Comment: As I understand no. There will be 15 distinct requests. They may all return the same thing, but they might not. When you talk about F5 do you mean F5 in a browser or does your application handle F5 and do some sort of refresh request?

Comment: No, I reffer to the f5 buttom. Why is different because if I go to Console > Network I see that all the request are made again @PaulRooney